# pythonで文字列にリスト中のすべての文字列が含まれているかを調べる方法

Tags: python, python3

pythonで文字列にリスト中のすべての文字列が含まれているかを調べたいです。
下記のように書くことはできたのですが、よりすっきりと書く方法はないでしょうか？

```py
words = ["python", "使える"]
text = "pythonがうまく使えるようになりたい。"

flag = True
for word in words:
    if word not in text:
        flag = False
print(flag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flagなどを使わないということなら

```py
print(
    all(w in text for w in words)
)
```